# Erro Conexão mysql e android

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc, conexão

Estou desenvolvendo um app que precisa ter uma conexão externa e estou tendo um problema na execução, como eu poderia resolver isso?

Segue o código:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

    public class conectar {
        Connection conn = null;
        public Connection getConexato() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.34:3306/localhost","root","");
            return conn;
        }
    }
```

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Connection conn = null;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;
    private String sql;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        conectar Conectar = new conectar();
        try {
            conn = Conectar.getConexato();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            msg.setTitle("Conctar!");
            msg.setMessage("Erro! " + e);
            msg.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
            msg.show();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            msg.setTitle("Conctar!");
            msg.setMessage("Erro! " + e);
            msg.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
            msg.show();
        }
        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btntest);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                msg.setTitle("Conctar!");
                msg.setMessage("Conectado!");
                msg.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                msg.show();
                try {
                    conn.close();
                    msg.setTitle("Conctar!");
                    msg.setMessage("Desconectado!");
                    msg.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                    msg.show();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Logcat:

> ```
> Error:PARSE ERROR:
> Error:unsupported class file version 52.0
> Error:...while parsing com/mysql/jdbc/JDBC42CallableStatement.class
> Error:1 error; aborting
> :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> ```
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Em uma rapida pesquisa achei esse link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902840/got-unsupported-class-file-version-52-0-after-including-a-module-to-a-project veja se é o mesmo caso seu.

Comment: Infelizmente não é o mesmo  Caso, testei essa solução mas não funcionou ... obrigado assim Cara!

Comment: Eu tenho um link no projeto no github talvez possa ajudar, a coneção está funcionando corretamente, ignore as gambiarras kkk https://github.com/luizfps/GLCMonitor

Comment: vou tentar estudar o codigo aqui e te retorno! valeu

Answer (score 0):

O erro acontece porque você não especificou as opções de compatibilidade no próprio módulo. Geralmente acontece se o seu projeto está com **JDK 7**, mas está instalado e usando **JDK 8**, em seguida, todos os módulos que serão usados em um projeto tem que ser compatível com o **JDK 7**. Caso contrário, haverá um erro porque o JDK 7 não é possível analisar arquivos de classe que foram compilados pela JDK 8 e têm a versão 52.

Verifique:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
```

Detalhes

- [Source (Stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902840/got-unsupported-class-file-version-52-0-after-including-a-module-to-a-project)

Comment: Verifiquei e Realmente NÃO tinha, MAS na hora que coloquei e sincronizei hum Gradle, e Aconteceu Esse Erro aqui:   Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.